# Чем отличаются эти два кода в tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gui, инспекция-кода, tkinter

Есть кнопка-изображение, при нажатии на которую должно меняться состояние `self.ANX` (True/False) и изображение на самой кнопке (для состояния True одно, для False - другое).

Какой из этих вариантов лучше подходит для моей задачи и в чем отличия в их работе?

Первый вариант с self.кнопкой и self.методом для кнопки:

```
def create_frames(self):
    sidebar_frame = tk.Frame(self)

    ...

    # Кнопка: ANX (on/off)
    self.ANX = False

    ANXon_button_image = tk.PhotoImage(file='./img/sidebar/ANX_on.png')
    ANXoff_button_image = tk.PhotoImage(file='./img/sidebar/ANX_off.png')
    self.ANX_button = tk.Button(sidebar_frame, image=ANXoff_button_image,
                                bd=0, command=self.ANX_button_clicked)
    self.ANX_button.onimg = ANXon_button_image
    self.ANX_button.offimg = ANXoff_button_image
    self.ANX_button.place(width=137, height=31, x=17, y=13)

def ANX_button_clicked(self):
    if self.ANX is False:
        self.ANX = True
        self.ANX_button['image'] = self.ANX_button.onimg
    else:
        self.ANX = False
        self.ANX_button['image'] = self.ANX_button.offimg
```

Второй вариант с кнопкой (без self) и обычной функцией внутри метода:

```
def create_frames(self):
    sidebar_frame = tk.Frame(self)

    ...

    # Кнопка: ANX (on/off)
    self.ANX = False

    def ANX_button_clicked():
        if self.ANX is False:
            self.ANX = True
            ANX_button['image'] = ANX_button.onimg
        else:
            self.ANX = False
            ANX_button['image'] = ANX_button.offimg

    ANXon_button_image = tk.PhotoImage(file='./img/sidebar/ANX_on.png')
    ANXoff_button_image = tk.PhotoImage(file='./img/sidebar/ANX_off.png')
    ANX_button = tk.Button(sidebar_frame, image=ANXoff_button_image,
                           bd=0, command=ANX_button_clicked)
    ANX_button.onimg = ANXon_button_image
    ANX_button.offimg = ANXoff_button_image
    ANX_button.place(width=137, height=31, x=17, y=13)
```

Пытался использовать `tkinter.Checkbutton`, но этот способ работает не так, как надо.

Comment: если вы уверены, что оба примера кода работают и допустимы ответы, которые предлагают любые улучшения, то добавьте метку [tag:code-review] (прочтите её описание, чтобы быть увереным, что вопрос соответствует требованиям)¶ Если не уверены, что код работает, то лучше вопрос задать в форме: "Как реализовать on/off кнопку с картинками в tkinter".

Comment: @jfs Добавил метку, спасибо, не знал про неё. Нужно ли дополнить код для этой метки всеми необходимыми деталями (`import`, `class`, etc), чтобы код можно сразу запустить? Потому что код здесь рабочий, но детали опущены, чтобы лишнего не пришлось читать.

Comment: задача [tag:code-review] чтобы автор кода научился чему-нибудь. Отсутствие контекста (... в коде) или искусственный пример могут скрыть реальные проблемы в коде. Подробнее: [Why is hypothetical example code off-topic for Code Review?](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1709/why-is-hypothetical-example-code-off-topic-for-code-review)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция внутри метода, называется [замыкание](http://blog.jetfix.ru/post/zamykaniya-v-python-chto-eto-i-s-chem-ih-edyat).
Не думаю, что ее использование, оправдано в конкретном случае. Мой вариант такой:

```
import tkinter as tk

class WIND(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.ANX = False
        # поместив все фото в словарь, ключами которого будут значения self.ANX,
        # можно избавится от проверок if self.ANX is..., особенно для более чем двух состояний(True/False)
        self.ANX_photo = {True: tk.PhotoImage(file='1.png'),
                          False: tk.PhotoImage(file='2.png')}

        self.button = tk.Button(self, command=self.button_cmd)

        # можно определить self.ANX = tk.BooleanVar() и задать в checkbutton(variable=tk.BooleanVar)
        # тогда чекбокс автоматически бы изменял состояние self.ANX, но при этом в self.set_ANX выполнять self.ANX = not self.ANX не надо
        self.checkbutton = tk.Checkbutton(self, command=self.set_ANX)

        self.button.pack()
        self.checkbutton.pack()
        self.set_ANX()

    def set_ANX(self, *args):
        # должно меняться состояние self.ANX
        self.ANX = not self.ANX
        # состояние self.button
        self.button.config(image=self.ANX_photo[self.ANX],  # можно избавится от проверок if self.ANX is...
                           state='normal' if self.ANX else 'disabled')

    def button_cmd(self):
        '''кнопка может изменять состояние self.ANX и выполнить дополнительную работу,
        если бы set_ANX было замыканием, то сослатся на нее отсюда, стало бы невозможно'''
        self.set_ANX()
        print(self.ANX)

WIND().mainloop()
```